# vim setwidth equivalent in emacs

Tags: linux, vim, emacs

I am new to emacs and I am trying to get this functionality going.

What I want to do have is whenever I am writing C (or generally programming, actually) code to have the editor force a column bound so whenever I go more than 80 lines it automatically starts a new line.

In vim, I do that with:
`set textwidth=80`
`set nowrap`

How do I do that in .emacs file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`auto-fill-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Fill.html).

This should do what you want:

```
(setq-default fill-column 80)
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)
```

Comment: I tried that before but somehow it didn't work (as in, it didn't do anything at all).

Comment: @xci13, my mistake, before it only enabled `auto-fill` for the current buffer. Please try the new version.